# Keep getting this error constantly- Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'poi_id' at row 1 )

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Okay so i keep getting "Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'poi_id' at row 1
)" and the variables specified are not AUTO_INCREMENT. Here is my code:

```
             <?php


   header("Content-type: application/json");


  $pi= $_POST["poi_ID"];
$rev= $_POST["review"];



$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=name;", "name","name");





$results = $conn->query("SELECT*FROM pointsofinterest");


  $results= $conn -> query ("INSERT INTO poi_reviews(poi_id, review) VALUES 
  ('$pi', '$rev')");



  echo json_encode($resultsAsAssocArray) ;

 print_r($conn->errorinfo());                        
  ?>
```

Comment: which RDBMS is this, mysql or mssql? 2 different animals here.

Comment: Please read about [SQL Injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner i think its the former

Comment: @marvinIsSacul I tend to think so also. :) but that made their question unclear, given people following any of those tags.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner It is mysql. However MSSQL is tagged, mysql is specified in connection string. I am assuming the OP thinks the problem is independent of sql flavour.

Comment: @Harsh It's hard to say. PDO can be used in MSSQL and the OP hasn't responded to my earlier comment, therefore and as my vote to close earlier still stands, being unclear.

Answer (score 1):

If `$poi_id` is an Integer, you mustn't put apostrophes around it.
Also your code does not assure that `$pi` is an Integer value. Try casting `$pi` to an Integer and inserting that instead of the raw POST data.